# Gmail Image Proxy returns an internal error (500), email images are not displayed

Tags: iis, gmail, web-config, content-security-policy

So, here's the behavior we found...

When accessing this link below (which is sent through gmail) the image does not display and it returns a http error 500.

https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/3gt-wvd5UuioHeK9S2r2nZ04uwODm4Dn03RjbQaMNtKs-AGGB4DFkbmxnvJvUj8ha-eVU2LdIdEI5JAeD0JjYLdqjdQoS5sRo_YW-XXp_IaF93LHbEakIg=s0-d-e1-ft#https://[someURL]

The culprit we found is that it is because of the CSP header.
If we removed the following from our web.config:

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="img-src 'self' data: blob: [some values]">
<add name="X-Content-Security-Policy" value="img-src 'self' data: blob: [some values]">
<add name="X-Webkit-CSP" value="img-src 'self' data: blob: [some values]">
```

The image is now being displayed.

The issue is that we cannot remove these tags for security concerns.
What can we do so that the images can be displayed again from gmail?
What URLs should we add to our csp policies?

We've already tried the following without any luck:

```
img-src 'self' data: blob: https://*.googleusercontent.com
img-src 'self' data: blob: https://*.ggpht.com
img-src 'self' data: blob: http://*.googleusercontent.com
img-src 'self' data: blob: http://*.ggpht.com
```

Has anyone already solved the issue?
Are we doing something wrong with the CSP header above?

Answer (score 0):

I have the equal issue and I find out this root cause too. If I drop this header X-Webkit-CSP the images displayed correctly. Could you share any information with me about solving this issue. My email is vzrivpaket22@gmail.com